# viewDidDisappear not getting called on a UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having a problem with my navigation controller. If I add a view controller to the stack:

```
- (void) tui_ToggleListStudy:(id)sender
{
    listVC = [[ListViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:listVC animated:NO];
    [listVC release];
}
```

I have NSLog messages for the view controller beneath, for both `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear` - but only `viewWillDisappear:` is getting called.

Not only that, but the view controller doesn't receive any other delegate messages either: No `viewDidUnload`, or `dealloc`...

Is there anything I can do about this?

I'm stumped! Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the answer if you made the same typo in your code that you made in your question: the method signature is `viewDidDisappear:` (with the `animated` argument), not `viewDidDisappear`.

> Not only that, but the view controller doesn't receive any other delegate messages either: No viewDidUnload, or dealloc...

A view controller will not be deallocated when you push another controller onto the stack. And `viewDidUnload` won't be called unless you run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks! Bizarrely, I was using autocomplete and XCode doesn't give you viewDidDisappear: , it gives you just viewDidDisappear! I naturally assumed this was correct, because you're more likely to want to know in "will" than "did" if there is GOING to be animation, rather than it WAS animated. Still, sorted now thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your navigation controller is contained in some kind of top view controller, you must also forward the relevant messages from that top view controller to the nav controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [navController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [navController viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [navController viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [navController viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call super at implementation of viewWillDisappear.

Comment: It's not viewWillDisappear where the problem is, it's viewDidDisappear. And even if I wasn't calling super, it would still trace because it is at the top of the chain...

Comment: @Prcela, thanks. If [super viewWillDisappear:animated] is not called in viewWillDisappear, the viewDidDisappear will NOT be called.

Answer (score 0):

The designated initializer for UIViewController is `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. Are you sure your view controller is finding its nib and finds its connected view? I'll bet if you set a breakpoint after init'ing your ListViewController, you'll find its -view returns nil.

Comment: I used to do it that way, but according to the Stanford lectures, it automatically finds the nob file with the same name if you don't declare it. I did what you suggested anyway, and the view isn't nil.